# How to compare string which contains integers in JAVA

Tags: java, android, string

I have some problem with comparing strings which contain integers.
Something like `A11` and `A9` or `BA230` and `BA7` or `123` and `9`
I know when I want to compare integers (which are string types), I need to pass into Integer and compare
But this is not that case.

It also contains letters and numbers so I can't pass into Integer.

When I compare `A11` and `A9` using `compareTo` method, it says `A9` is bigger.
And when I compare `123` with `9` it says `9` is bigger.

Has anyone faced this issue before? 
Could you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the alphanumeric strings will contain letters first and then numbers?

Comment: `"A11"` is considered greater than `"A9"` due to a comparison of the `char`s per index. In this case `"A"` and `"A"` are equal, so the next comparison of `"1"` and `"9"` finds out that `9 > 1` and the comparison stops with a result.

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: It's Java, But if you give me solution with javascript, I can convert it to Java

Comment: @Jabongg nope, It's not guaranteed

Comment: @MobileStar no, you likely cannot, otherwise you'd have done that.

Comment: Is `A11 < 11A` or `A11 > 11A` or `A11 = 11A` ?

Comment: try comparator. See this link for your reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036155/sorting-numeric-string-interval-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * Similar to compareTo method But compareTo doesn't return correct result for string+integer strings something like `A11` and `A9`
  */

private int newCompareTo(String comp1, String comp2) {
    // If any value has 0 length it means other value is bigger
    if (comp1.length() == 0) {
        if (comp2.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    } else if (comp2.length() == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Check if first string is digit
    if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(comp1)) {
        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(comp1);
        // Check if second string is digit
        if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(comp2)) { // If both strings are digits then we only need to use Integer compare method
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(comp2);
            return Integer.compare(val1, val2);
        } else { // If only first string is digit we only need to use String compareTo method
            return comp1.compareTo(comp2);
        }

    } else { // If both strings are not digits

        int minVal = Math.min(comp1.length(), comp2.length()), sameCount = 0;

        // Loop through two strings and check how many strings are same
        for (int i = 0;i < minVal;i++) {
            char leftVal = comp1.charAt(i), rightVal = comp2.charAt(i);
            if (leftVal == rightVal) {
                sameCount++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sameCount == 0) {
            // If there's no same letter, then use String compareTo method
            return comp1.compareTo(comp2);
        } else {
            // slice same string from both strings
            String newStr1 = comp1.substring(sameCount), newStr2 = comp2.substring(sameCount);
            if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(newStr1) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(newStr2)) { // If both sliced strings are digits then use Integer compare method
                return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(newStr1), Integer.parseInt(newStr2));
            } else { // If not, use String compareTo method
                return comp1.compareTo(comp2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String extractNumber(final String str) {                

if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) return "";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean found = false;
for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
    if(Character.isDigit(c)){
        sb.append(c);
        found = true;
    } else if(found){
        // If we already found a digit before and this char is not a digit, stop looping
        break;                
    }
}

return sb.toString();
}
```

For input "123abc", the method above will return 123.

For "abc1000def", 1000.

For "555abc45", 555.

For "abc", will return an empty string.

// Then you can parse that to integer and then compare

Comment: Hmm.. how about `A3` and something like `9`?
`A3` is supposed to be after than `9` as sql `order_by` does

Comment: ya if you get the integer from that text or string  then you can easily use compare to function !!!

Comment: i think this will result `A3` is before `9`

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        int len1 = value.length;
        int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;

        int k = 0;
        while (k < lim) {
            char c1 = v1[k];
            char c2 = v2[k];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                return c1 - c2;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
```

String.compareTo is compare every character's unicode value one by one.
it will return when find that two character not equal.

A11 compare to A9:

step1: 'A' compare to 'A'

step2: '1' compare to '9' . '1' unicode value is 49, '9' unicode value is 57.

So A9 is bigger.

*order_by* is the same as above .

[order_by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc55a.png)